# svcutil namespace on properties not generated

Tags: c#, wsdl

I have used svcutil to generate the below code using a wsdl . But the 'NameSpace' on the XmlElementAttribute is not set at the property level. Is there some setting I am missing here ?

The 'NameSpace' at the class level in the attribute XmlTypeAttribute is generated fine .

I have a previously generated code for the same wsdl with 'NameSpace' value  set at the property level . Just wondering If I have missed a setting .I have checked the documentation in msdn , but could not find any flag that could be set to make this work .

Any suggestion to fix this issue ?

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "custom-message", Namespace =     "http://tat.com/bba/mprovider")]
    public partial class custommessage
    {   
        private information informationField;
        private int typeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ivr-information", Order = 0)]
        public information information
        {
            get;            
            set;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XML namespace is inherited. This means that if both custom-message and ivr-information have the same namespace it is only generated on parent element and children inherit this namespace.

Comment: Do you mean you want to force generation of namespace on XML element? You don't need that, because the actual namespace is correctly inherited from the parent

Comment: Also , Name space is not set on properties which is not same as the parent namespace . It is generated only at the class level for some reason

Comment: I am trying to do it since the service is not able to return the response object without the name space . I have put them manually now to make it work .